# Close I frame Video by onclick

Tags: iframe

I just want to know how do I close popup iframe in a page by clicking button and also it should show only one time to user. If i have login the second it should not show to me. If i am login first time it show the popup video.

Regards,
Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

This cat can be skinned more than one way.

lets see if this works:

1. set a variable in js outside method so that it has global scope
2. when document ready, check if variable is set, if not set, show your iframe
3. before you show the iframe, set the variable so that the 2nd time, condition is false and so the iframe is not shown
4. make sure you give the iframe a unique id (ie:   id="poponceiframe"  )
5. have a button witin your iframe that close by using something like onclick="parent.$('#poponceiframe').css('display','none');"

I think that should work - something like this:

```
<script>
  poppedOnce=(poppedOnce === undefined || poppedOnce === 'undefined')?false:poppedOne;
  $(document).ready( function () {
   if(!poppedOnce) {
     poppedOnce=true;
     $("#poponceifram").css("display","block");
   }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see the code below. How to add condition here for popup.

Comment: IN the continue button click it show close popup and show the page. If user come to page second time it wont show popup</div>
  <a class="close-btn"  href="#"><span class="continue" id="continue">Continue </span>
</a>
                <a href="javacript: window.parent.closeIframe()">Continue </a>
 </div>
</section>